# How to get the first value of array inside an arrayList c#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I need to get the value codTabla from inside the arraylist. how can iterate

```
ArrayList arrayList= new ArrayList();
string[] data = new string[] {codTabla,codCalificadoAsignado,codSolicitudVisado};
arrayList.Add(data);
```

Comment: Why are you using the old fashioned and busted `Arraylist` and not the more modern `List<T>`

Answer (score 0):

data[0] will give you first element.

```
ArrayList arrayList= new ArrayList();
string[] data = new string[] {codTabla,codCalificadoAsignado,codSolicitudVisado};
arrayList.Add(data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop like this:

```
  //you don't need cast becouse the type of the item in the foreach loop is 
 //string[] or whatever you want it    
 foreach(string[] item in arrayList)
 {
   //using index 0 for access the first element of codTabla array
   Console.Writeline(item[0]);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

As the indexer of an `ArrayList`returns `object`, you need to cast the first element in your `ArrayList` to `string[]`. Then you can access it via the indexer:

```
string myValue = ((string[])arrayList[0])[0];
```

Note that this only works if your `ArrayList` *does* in fact contain a non empty `string[]` as it's first element. To be safe, you should do some checks:

```
string myValue = null;

// make sure, arrayList contains a first element
if (arrayList.Count > 0)
{
    // obtain the first element if it is a string[] and make sure
    // it contains a first element
    var arr = arrayList[0] as string[];
    if (arr != null && arr.Length > 0)
    {
        myValue = arr[0];
    }
}
```

Nevertheless you should consider using a `List<string[]>` instead of an `ArraList` as @MichaelRandall suggested in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63916794#comment113024685_63916794).